# Small signal equivalent circuit - MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pmos, small-signal

Let's consider the following amplifier circuit:

[image]

Now, if we would analyze small signal operation, we could represent the circuit with small signal equivalent:

[image]

The part that bothers me is the PMOS representation in my workbook. Shouldn't the voltage controlled current source of the PMOS transistor (index 2 in the drawing) be rotated so that the current goes from its source to drain?

Comment: Is gm2 positive or negative?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Transconductance is a positive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxDP0h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage gain is:

\$ \large \frac{V_{OUT}}{r_x} + g_{m1}*V_{IN} - g_{m2}*(-V_{OUT}) = 0\$

Where \$r_x = r_{o1}||r_{o2}\$

$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = - \frac{g_{m1}*r_x}{1 + g_{m2}*r_x} = - g_{m1}*\left(r_{o1}||r_{o2}||\frac{1}{g_{m2}}\right) $$

And now let us analysis this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmylb.png)</sup>

As you can see I used the N-MOS small-signal equivalent circuit for the P-MOS this time.

\$ \large \frac{V_{OUT}}{r_x} + g_{m1}*V_{IN} + g_{m2}*V_{OUT} = 0\$

And the voltage gain is exactly the same as before.

\$ \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = - \frac{g_{m1}*r_x}{1 + g_{m2}*r_x} = - g_{m1}*\left(r_{o1}||r_{o2}||\frac{1}{g_{m2}}\right)\$

So to conclude it may sound strange at first glance but P-MOS circuit small signal model is identical to N-MOS.

We have the same situation with the BJT's

[Why are the current directions in the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model for BJT the same for both NPN and PNP?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78781/why-are-the-current-directions-in-the-hybrid-pi-model-for-bjt-the-same-for?rq=1)

[Applying hybrid-pi model of an npn-BJT to a pnp BJT in small signal analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/88059/applying-hybrid-pi-model-of-an-npn-bjt-to-a-pnp-bjt-in-small-signal-analysis?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Part annoying me in your text book is that they didn’t substitute the diode connected PMOS with a resistor (1/gm2)//ro2

For your question, the small signal model remains same in both nome and pmos because it is actually a current source whose direction is from source to drain, it’s value should be (gm*vsg) which is same as (gm*-vgs) which is same as (gm*vgs) in opposite direction (from drain to source)